# Trouble printing array of titles and urls

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I'm not very good at PHP.

I have a folder of .html files that will change often, and then  I want to search through the folder, parse the `<h1>` tags, and then print/echo each `<h1>` tag and its url.

Getting the `<h1>` tags out of the .html files was easy enough with some Googling, but I cannot seem to print a list of `<h1>` titles and their corresponding URL's.

Here is what I have so far:

```php
        $url_list = glob('posts/*.html'); // Searches for all files and folders in above directory that end in .html.

        foreach ($url_list as $url) { // Creates an array of post URL's and title <h1> tags.
            $post = new DOMDocument(); // Creates string to load blog post.
            $post->loadHTMLFile($url); // Loads blog post into string $post from its URL.

            $h1_tags = $post->getElementsByTagName('h1'); // Finds all <h1> tags.
            $first_h1 = $h1_tags->item(0); // Gets value of first <h1> tag.
            $title = $first_h1->nodeValue; // Sets $title to value of first <h1> tag.

            if (!empty($title)) { // Will only run on files which have a date in their metadata.
                $post_list[$url] = $title;
                $post_list[$title] = $url;
            }
        }

        sort($post_list); // Sorts list of posts in alphabetical order.

        $num = 1;

        foreach ($post_list as $title) { //
            echo "<a href=\"{$url}\"><h2>".($num++).". {$title} = {$url}</h2></a>";
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding the titles and URL's into the same list - but reversed.  If you build up your data as...

```
        if (!empty($title)) { // Will only run on files which have a date in their metadata.
            $post_list[$title] = $url;
        }
```

So this only adds it in once, and then output it like...

```
    foreach ($post_list as $title => $url) { //
        echo "<a href=\"{$url}\"><h2>".($num++).". {$title} = {$url}</h2></a>";
    }
```

Edit: change `sort()` to `asort()`

Comment: Thanks, that sorts out the URL's, but for some reason the titles that I want to print just come out as 0, 1, 2 ... etc, instead of the title that I wanted from the <h1> tags. What am I still doing wrong?

Comment: That is probably just the output of `$num++`.  You may have to check that in the loop where you set them, you are getting a value for `$title = $first_h1->nodeValue;`.  If you have a sample HTML page I could try out then I would be able to check it.

Comment: Unfortunately not, I have completely removed the `$num++` and it gives the same problem. If I do a `var_dump($post_list)` it gives me this result: `array(5) { [0]=> string(17) "posts/bumble.html" [1]=> string(17) "posts/eighth.html" [2]=> string(16) "posts/fifth.html" [3]=> string(16) "posts/tenth.html" [4]=> string(16) "posts/third.html" }`

Comment: Ah - you need to use [`asort($post_list);`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php) as the keys are removed by `sort()`.

Comment: AHA! Thanks, Nigel! I never knew `sort()` did that! Problem solved!